# File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\n1.py", line 42 else: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, error404

```
from time import sleep
from termcolor import colored
import turtle
import random
name = input("What's your name?:")
print("Hello", name)
sleep(1)
def menu():
 print("___MENU___")
 print("1.Start")
 print("2.Flight start")
 print("3.Continue a story")
menu()
def choose():
   choose1 = input("Choose:")
   if choose1 == "1":
    print("Name of the ship: Apollo 1") 
    login = input("Login:") #Login is NASA
   if login =="NASA":
    passwd = input("Password:") #Passwd is Armstrong
   if passwd =="Armstrong":
    print("Sucсess!")
    sleep(1)
    print("Now let's get down to option 2!")
   if chhose1 == "2":
    dog = turtle.Turtle()
    dog.speed(0)
    okno = turtle.Screen()
    okno.setup(800, 600) # Устанавливаем размер окна
    okno.bgcolor('black') # Делаем задний фон зеленым
    dog.hideturtle() # убираем видимость курсора

    def star(n, dlina, col):
     dog.begin_fill() # Начало функции заливки
     if n % 2 != 0: # Проверяем на четность
      for i in range(n):
       dog.color(col) # Цвет нашей звезды
       dog.forward(dlina)
       y = n // 2 * 360 / n # Формула расчета угла
       dog.left(y)
     
    else: 
       n = n + 1 # Если количество вершин было четное, прибавляем 1
       star(n, dlina, col) # Вызываем нашу функцию
       dog.end_fill() # Конец функции заливки
       for i in range (150):
       x = random.randint(-350, 350) # Случайные координаты по х
       y = random.randint(-250, 250) # Случайные координаты по у
       dog.up() # Поднимаем карандаш
       dog.setposition (x,y)# Перемещаемся по координатам
       dog.down()# Опускаем карандаш
       size = random.randint (10, 30) # Случайный размер от 10 до 30
       ver = random.randint (5, 15) # Случайное кол-во вершин от 5 до 15

       star(ver, size, 'yellow') # При вызове функции передаем еще один аргумент, ЦВЕТ

       turtle.mainloop()
   if сhoose1 == "3":
    print("You see an alien and wonder what to do?")
    print("1.Launch a rocket")
    print("2.make contact with an alien lifeform")
   choose2 = input("Your decision?:")
   if choose2 =="2":
        def talk():
         print("You land your ship next to a UFO and go not to meet an alien")
         sleep(2)
         print("Alien:Who are you?")
         sleep(0.2)
         print("1.I am human from planet 'Eath'(Positive)")
         print("2.You shouldn't care (Negative)")
         choose3 = input("You say:")
         if choose3 =="1":
           print("Alien:Very good,I just wanted to talk with humans")
         if choose3 =="2":
           print("It was a very rude answer that the alien did not appreciate.")
           sleep(1)
           print("Alien:Well,since this is so, then you are going to die now")
           sleep(1)
           print("The alien killed you with his blaster,but your team escaped successfully,leaving your corpse flying through the endless expanse of space")
           print("People declared war on aliens,but our technologies were so weak that humanity surrendered to aliens")
           sleep(1)
           print(colored("Bad Ending", 'red'))
        talk()
         while True
          flag =input("Back to the beginning?[Yes/No]:")

          if flag =="Yes":
             talk()
          else:
             break


choose()
while True:
 flag =input("Return to menu? [Yes/No]:")

 if flag =="Yes":
    menu()
 else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендуется использовать 4 пробела на уровень отступа. Python 3 запрещает смешивать табуляцию и пробелы в отступах. Код, в котором используются оба типа отступов, должен быть исправлен так, чтобы отступы были только пробелами.
Рекомендуется использовать 4 пробела на уровень отступа. Python 3 запрещает смешивать табуляцию и пробелы в отступах. Код, использующий оба типа отступов, должен быть исправлен так, чтобы отступы были только с пробелами.

Переведено с помощью [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (бесплатная версия)

**Правильно**

```
def no_tab_using():
    no_tab = 'Using 4 spaces'
```

**Плохо**

```
def no_tab_using():
  no_tab = 'Using 4 spaces'
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык